# How to check if a post "does not have term" in conditional statement?

Tags: wp-query, conditional-tags

We know that we can check if the particular post has a term by using this code:

```
has_term('term', 'taxonomy', $post->ID )) {
```

I was wondering if there is a code to check if a particular post does not have a particular term.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question because you can use the same code for checking if a post doesn't have a term..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ( !has_term('term', 'taxonomy', $post->ID )) {
```

Use the NOT (`!`) operator

Comment: Added a bit more info as your post will auto flag as low quality ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
function myFunction() {
    $value = "";
    if( has_term( 'myterm', 'taxonomy' ) ) {
            $value = "foo";
    }
    elseif( has_term( 'nextterm', 'taxonomy' ) ) {
        $value = "nextfoo";
    }
        if( !empty( $value ) ) {
        echo 
        //do something with 
        $value;
    }
}
```